# Overlapping of elements in CSS

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-selectors

I have to implement the design given below in which phone's image is both inside and out of the orange background. At top it is out of the background and at bottom it's inside.

If I use z-index here, then phone's image can be either completely inside of the background or completely outside.

Any idea how to implement this?

[image]

Here is the full image of phone

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three alternatives, while the first one does the trick, the second and third ones are more versatile; they can be used for all kinds of clipping shapes.

---

**Option 1:** In CSS, you can use two overlapped phone images:

The inner image is clipped on the bottom by the circle shape of its wrapping div. This is done with `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden`.

The outer image (on top) is clipped around its vertical middle, using a rectangle shape.

Therefore, you'll see the top and bottom halves of the phone from two images, outer and inner, respectively.

```css
.out {
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.out>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 90px 0);
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.inner img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="inner">
    <img width="200" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMrYZ.png" />
  </div>

  <img width="200" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMrYZ.png" />
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/efortis/2dv5qkmg

---

**Option 2:** SVG, in which there's only image and the clipping mask of the phone is a custom shape. For your case, the shape is a rectangle plus a semi-circle on the bottom:

```
  +------+
  |      |
  |      |
  +-    -+
    \__/
```

```html
<svg width="350" height="350" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 350 350" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs >
    <clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="RoundedBottomMask">
      <path d="m -1,-0.4 v 196 h 50 a 125,125 0 0 0 125,120 125,125 0 0 0 125,-120 h 51.9 v -196 z" fill="#ee7500"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle
    id="clip"
    cx="173.8"
    cy="190.10001"
    r="125"
    fill="orange"
    />
  <image
    width="224.42018"
    height="290.29099"
    preserveAspectRatio="none"
    xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMrYZ.png"
    x="49.370064"
    y="24.956205"
    clip-path="url(#RoundedBottomMask)"/></svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/efortis/5w0rm27b/1/

---

**Option 3:** you can combine both methods by using use the SVG clip-path `#RoundedBottomMask`, as the source of the CSS `clip-path`.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74168748/529725

Comment: it is working but that's kinda low quality. I like the SVG one

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using only the image:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 999px 999px;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(50% 50%,orange 99%,#0000) 
   bottom/100% 71% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMrYZ.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  width: 800px;
  height: 900px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 999px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  height: 900px;
  justify-self: center;
  position: relative;
  grid-row: 1 \ 2;
  grid-column: 1 \ 2;
  z-index: 2;
}

.img-bg {
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  grid-row: 1 \ 2;
  grid-column: 1 \ 2;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e66f2a;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMrYZ.png" class="img" />
  <div class="img-bg"></div>
</div>
```

The main takeaway there is using `border-bottom-left-radius`, `border-bottom-right-radius` with `overflow: hidden`.

Hope it helps.